# Branching strategy for developing multiple features at the same time

Tags: git, branching, gitflow, strategy

We are doing a mobile app development and currently, we have `Dev` - `UAT` - `Staging` - `Main` branches.

We branch from the `Main` branch as `feature/fA` for feature development.
We do our development in that branch and when it is done, we create a merge request to the `Dev` branch. We go on with the tests and create a new merge request to the `UAT` branch if it looks good.

If the feature is approved to go live we create a merge request to `Staging`. `Staging` acts as our release candidate branch.

After releasing the application we merge `Staging` to `Main`, tag the release and update any ongoing features with `Main`.

Our problem is when we have multiple features going on at the same time, we face conflicts in our merge requests to `Dev`, and `UAT`.
While trying to solve these conflicts, we had to pull the code from `Dev` and `UAT` to our feature branches, which contain other features. Some of those features might not be going to release so this infects our feature branch.

Limitations:

We can't test each feature independently because we create test packages on a schedule and those packages need to contain multiple release candidate features.

Possible solutions that I found:

1. Feature toggle
2. Create an extra branch for each feature in order to merge to env. branches so if there is a conflict solving them won't affect the feature branch. But creates extra work and the way we solve conflicts in each branch and feature must be consistent.

Can you suggest a branching strategy that will minimize the conflict and/or keep our feature branches clean?

Comment: Branching can't fix a broken release and testing cycle.    The real problem is a lack of testing for individual features before merging into your `Dev` branch.    I would focus instead on changing the process used for generating test packages so that your testing is concentrated on features instead, triggering the package process from your Feature branches.

Comment: You do not. You practice continuous integration with trunk-based development, where there is single branch to which everyone commits at least once a day, with preference to more frequent integration. If there is feature you do not want to release, you put it behind feature toggle.

Comment: Feature toggles are good. Better if most code gets compiled except for a few lines that actually use the feature.

Comment: "we had to pull the code from Dev and UAT to our feature branches, which contain other features. Some of those features might not be going to release so this infects our feature branch." this seems wrong, can you clarify

Comment: Are you merging the feature branch into dev, and then re-merging the feature branch in UAT? Or are you merging dev into UAT?

Comment: In your case, an extra testing environment would help.  Instead of just DEV, you could have DEV1, DEV2.  Etc.  This would give an extra environment to test those features in isolation.  If everything looks good, then merge to dev, staging, uat, and eventually push to prod.  This would give your team the means test the feature in isolation prior to integration

Answer (score 1):

You should use GitFlow.

Instead of Staging and UAT branches, create release branches

If you find an issue when testing a release, branch from the release branch and fix it in a hotfix. Don't try to fix it in the original feature branch.

Comment: +1 Once a feature branch has been merged into an integration branch, the only way is forward. Fix it there. Don't go back to the feature branch. Consider it a dead branch. If you want to retain the history of that branch in version control, use a non fast-forward merge, otherwise a squash merge can keep history cleaner.

Comment: GIt flow as described on nvie.com doesn't have release branches. Releases are done from master in git flow.

Comment: who? https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow

Comment: also, you are wrong : https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Comment: It seems like so many answers to `git` questions on this stackexchange is “use Git Flow”. It seems very subcultural.

Comment: It does solve 99% of problems and has loads of documentation that makes it easy to follow. Occasionally you get a question : "how do i merge hotfixes when.." where its gets tricky, but most peoples problems with git are rebasing or like here, branches for versions